# My native query returns PGobjects instead of my entities - how can I achieve that?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm trying to get a JPA Function in Spring Boot returning my result as convenient as possible. I'm using PostgreSQL as my database.

I have a NativeQuery, which should return a List of objects with

```
TableObjectA
TableObjectB
double
```

value as its content.

Instead, I'm getting this:

```
PGObject
PGObject
double
```

How can I tell Spring JPA to return my actual entities instead of the "literal" result. Is there a convenient solution to this or do I really have to create several DTOs for this single method?

For clarification, this is my native query. `clubAddress` and `club` are defined as entities. Point is calculated.

```
SELECT clubAddress ,club, point(?1, ?2) <@> (point(clubAddress.longitude, clubAddress.latitude)\:\:point) as distance FROM club_address clubAddress,club_club club WHERE club.id = clubAddress.club_id
```

Comment: First define what you are calling a PGObject. Then supply your actual table definitions (ddl), sample data in the table format, and the expected results of that data - all as formatted text - **no images**. Also show what you have tried.

Comment: PGobject is the default object returned by postgre - PostgreObject. so to speak. Its from the driver library and contains only the values returned.

Comment: Sort of what I thought:  basically a Spring Boot object containing the **result set** from Postgres. Like wise then a TableObject is simply a table. Still, to answer we need sample test data, the query (or a representative sample), the actual results of that query, and the expected results.